# detect duplicate processor behaviour in apache Nifi

Tags: redis, apache-nifi

Detect duplicate processor has these props
[image: Detect Duplicate Processor Image]

Cache entry Identifier :  ( custom string combined of flowfile attributes)
Flowfile description : (empty)
Age off duration :  (empty because i am simply having TTL for redis entry)
Distributes map cache service :  ( which here i am using as redis distirbuted map cache service.)
cache the entry identifier: (false)

So I am using different processor to put keys into redis. But the thing is when I was using **Put Distributed Map Cache Processor**,  which puts value of the key as flowfile content, which is aain a single attribute value which is combination of a letter and numbers. and I have around 2000 entries let's say with TTL 26hours. Now the data passes through detect duplicate after 24 hours duplicates should dropped and non duplicates should be passed. Instead for some of the keys it's working correctly but then **I am getting array out of bound exception.**

To resolve this temporarily, I am using another Detect duplicate processor  as a proxy, to put the key in redis.

Now Detect duplicate is working normally, But still I am getting some duplicates passed from the Processor.

Can someone help me with this  ?